# Grails RestBuilder dont findendPoint with Object in signature

Tags: java, grails, groovy, restclientbuilder

I have a code with a RestBuilder that needs to connect to another application, the target endPoint have an object in the signature with the attributes. The problem is the request return 404. How I solve this? I tried use x-www-form-urlencoded (doesn't work)

Request Method:

```
RestResponse restResponse;

String parameters = '{"qtdThreads":3,"channel":"http://localhost:8081/application2"}'

try {
    restResponse = new RestBuilder().post("http://localhost:8080/application/endPoint", {
        accept("application/json")
        contentType "application/json; utf-8"
        body(parameters.getBytes("UTF-8"))
        connectTimeout: 1000
    })
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    return restResponse;
}
```

Target endPoint:

```
Object endPoint(ObjectCommand command) {
    render(status: HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Object used on signature

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

@Validateable
class ObjectCommand {

    URL channel
    Integer qtdThreads

    static constraints = {
        qtdThreads(validator: { Integer val ->
            if (!val || val <= 0) {
                return "message1"
            }
        })
        channel(validator: { URL val ->
            if (!val) {
                return "message2"
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Java 7 - 1.7.0_241
Grails 2.3.11

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the target application is running and exposing that endpoint?

Comment: Yes. The target application is running and endPoint is public.

Comment: And it's on port 8080?

Comment: What's the output of `curl -v http://localhost:8080/application/endPoint`?

Comment: Yeah 8080. The curl works.